# How can I match left and right parenthesis inside where clause?

Tags: pyparsing

```
 whereExpr=Forward()
 whereExpr = ((lpar + whereCond + rpar | whereCond) 
              + ((lpar + Optional((_and|_or) + whereExpr, '') + rpar)
                 | Optional((_and|_or) + whereExpr, ''))
             )
```

Now I want to match a where clause section like (seller != shop ) and ( b >=c or a <=d)

Comment: What have you tried before asking the question?

Comment: What happens if you use the '<<=' operator to assign the contents of `whereExpr` instead of `=` as you have now?

Comment: What I meant to say was that '=' is not the correct operator to use with Forward()'s, you need to use '<<=' or '<<'; otherwise to the expression will not match anything.

Comment: thanks. It's working. Previously  I didn't find any find differneces but now i can see.

Comment: `whereExpr <<= (whereCond|(lpar+whereCond+rpar)) + Optional((_and|_or)+((lpar+whereExpr+rpar)|(whereExpr)),'')`

Comment: thanks. It's working. Previously I didn't find any differneces but now i can see them clearly